# Excel duration between months - how to add additional rows to excel to show average time per month?

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula, powerbi

I have a basic Excel spreadsheet I am importing into Power BI to create a chart. The spreadsheet has over 300K rows of data, each row has a unique vehicle repair ID, with start date, finish date and time taken to complete the repair in decimal hours. It looks like the following:

**Repair ID | Start Date | Finish Date | Repair Time**

A32C____1 Jan 16____31 Mar 16___6.0

I need to produce a chart that will show all 12 months along the x-axis, with the average repair time, divided by the duration (start date to finish date), so I would have a chart that has Jan - 1 hr, Feb - 1hr, Mar - 1hr, in this case.

I need to get 3 additional rows made in excel with A32C on each row, and an extra col for Average Monthly Time, and an extra col for the months. Therefore I would need one row for each of the intervening months. It would look something like:

A32C would have 3 additional rows, one for Jan, Feb and March, with 1 hr for each. I can of course do this manually and import this new spreadsheet into Power BI to produce the chart, however my question is for a spreadsheet with over 300K rows - how (if at all) can I do this automatically?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to fix error with `CROSSJOIN` formula.

---

The way I would accomplish this (assuming you can't get the data at a level of hours per day) is to basically cross join your data with an existing table of months to create a brand new table with what you are looking for.

First, you will need a table with all of the months. If you already have one, great. If not, you can create one in PowerBI with this formula (on the Modeling tab, click New Table and enter this).

```
Months = FILTER(CALENDAR(DATE(2017,1,1), DATE(2017,12,31)), DAY([Date]) = 1)
```

[image: Month table]

Next, create a new table with this formula:

```
Results = FILTER(CROSSJOIN(Data, Months), Data[Start Date] <= Months[Date] && Data[Finish Date] >= Months[Date])
```

[image: Cross join table]

And finally, create an average repair time column with this formula (or a different one if you want to do different math).

```
AverageRepairTime = DIVIDE('Results'[Repair Time], CALCULATE(COUNT('Results'[Repair ID]), FILTER('Results', 'Results'[Repair ID] = EARLIER('Results'[Repair ID]))), 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Joe, thanks for taking the time to answer the question. It didnt quite work im afraid - in that when I set a month range, say from 1 Jan 16 to 31 Dec 17, any repair ID's that spanned across the year, didnt seem to be included. Also, some that should have produced 2 rows in the RESULTS table, produced, 3, some that should have produced 7, prioduced 8 etc. Im not sure whether it was to do with the month range, or whether the dates I have are UK dates, and power BI needs US dates? I am not sure how to upload screen shots to a comment? Cheers

Comment: So removing the .[MonthNo] seemed to fix it, but not sure why :-)

Results = FILTER(CROSSJOIN(Data, Months), Data[Start Date] <= Months[Date] && Data[Finish Date] >= Months[Date])

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that issue; it makes sense now. You want to be comparing the entire date, not just the month number. I've updated my answer with the corrected formula.

Comment: You are a star Joe, your answer helped me at work and will no doubt help others looking to do the same. Not sure why I got a down arrow, I couldnt find out how to do this anywhere else on stackoverflow.